# Domain controller not allowed to register its roles in DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp, rds

I'm adding a physical server (and some virtual hosts running on it) on a company network in the domain "comp.net". I'm not allowed to modify the DNS- or DHCP servers and cannot create any trusts between my servers and other company servers. I'm on a subnet with other servers. My servers run Windows Server 2019.

One of my servers is a remote desktop (RDS) server and I need to define my own users, so I figured I create a domain (forest) "proj.comp.net" and have my servers there. I have assigned one of my virtual servers "dc.proj.comp.net" the role of domain controller, but not the DNS role, as I was hoping to use the existing DNS server. The RDS server is "srv.proj.comp.net".

The fqdns correctly register in DNS and I can succesfully nslookup my servers. However, the company DNS server does not allow my dc to register it's domain controller role (nor other roles, e.g. kerberos server). The result is that "srv.proj.comp.net" doesn't find its domain controller.

Should I try to force my "srv.proj.comp.net" to use "dc.proj.comp.net" as domain controller somehow, through e.g. /etc/lmhosts or some registry setting? Or would it work better if I add the DNS role to "dc.proj.comp.net", somehow force "srv.proj.comp.net" to use this DNS, and try to tweak "dc" to forward everything from the company DNS, adding records related to it's roles?

Neither way seems simple so perhaps I'm on the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

An Active Directory domain can't exist without a matching DNS zone; if you want to create your own domain and are unable to integrate with the existing DNS servers, you need to use your own one.

You need to install the DNS role on your DC and configure the server to use itself as DNS; you should also create a forward DNS zone (AD-integrated) for your domain, because this has not been done during the DC promotion.

You can configure the DNS service on your DC to use the existing DNS servers on your network as forwarders; this will allow it to send all queries for zones it doesn't own to your company's DNS servers.

And yes, all servers and clients which need to join your domain will need to use your DC as their DNS server, in order to be able to retrieve the DNS records for your domain.

Comment: The DNS would have to forward queries about host in my zone as well, because the company DHCP/DNS handles dynamic host/ip assignment, right? Only queries about the DC itself (which therefore needs to have static IP) should not be forwarded. Is that correct?

Comment: No, your company's DNS servers can't handle queries about your "proj.comp.net" subdomain, because they don't know about it at all; also, all member computers of this "proj.comp.net" domain will need to use it as their DNS suffix and your DC as their DNS servers. You can't rely on your company's DHCP for that, you'll need static IP config on all your domain computers.